# Как подставить переменную в текст?

Tags: javascript

Есть запись вида:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>Онлайн конструктор визиток</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add').click(function(){
            $('<li><input type="text"><button class="btn btn-primary">+</button></li>').insertBefore('ul');
        });

        function refresh()
        {
            window.location.reload(); //window.location.href
            //confirm('Вы уверенны, что хотите перезагрузить страницу? На странице может использоваться введенная Вами информация, при перезагрузке она будет потерянна! Продолжить?');
        }

        //Функция red_line(), которая рисует защитные красные пунктирные линии
        function red_line()
        {
            var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = elem.getContext('2d');

            context.beginPath();

            for (var x1 = 20; x1 < 480; x1 += 40) 
            {
                context.moveTo(x1, 20);
                context.lineTo(x1+20, 20);
            };

            for (var y1 = 20; y1 < 480; y1 += 40) 
            {
                context.moveTo(480, y1);
                context.lineTo(480, y1+20);
            };

            for (var x2 = 20; x2 < 480; x2 += 40) 
            {
                context.moveTo(x2, 480);
                context.lineTo(x2+20, 480);
            };

            for (var y2 = 20; y2 < 480; y2 += 40) 
            {
                context.moveTo(20, y2);
                context.lineTo(20, y2+20);
            };

            context.strokeStyle = "#f00";
            context.lineWidth = 1;
            context.stroke();
        }

        //Функция grid(), которая рисует сетку
        function grid()
        {
            var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = elem.getContext('2d');

            //рисование вертикальных линий
            for (var x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 10)
            {
                context.moveTo(x, 0);
                context.lineTo(x, 500);
            }

            //рисование горизонтальных линий
            for (var y = 0.5; y < 500; y += 10)
            {
                context.moveTo(0, y);
                context.lineTo(500, y);
            }

            context.strokeStyle = "#eee";
            context.lineWidth = 0.5;
            context.stroke();
        }

        //Вызываем функцию, которая рисует защитные красные пунктирные линии
        red_line();

        //Вызываем функцию grid(), которая рисует сетку
        grid();

        //Записываем выбранный посетителем шрифт в переменную font
        $('#font').blur(function(){
            var font = document.getElementById('font').value;
            alert(font);//отладка
        });

        //Записываем выбранный посетителем шрифт в переменную font1 (bold, italic или underline)
        $('#font1').blur(function(){
            var font1 = document.getElementById('font1').value;
            alert(font1);//отладка
        });

        //Сохраняем то, что посетители вводят в значение полей в переменные
        $('#surname').blur(function(){
            var surname = $('#surname').val();
            //alert(surname); //отладка
            function fill_surname()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "bold 35px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(surname, 40, 120);
            }
            fill_surname();
        });

        $('#name').blur(function(){
            var name = $('#name').val();
            //alert(name); //отладка
            function fill_name()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "bold 20px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(name, 40, 160);
            }
            fill_name();
        });

        $('#middle_name').blur(function(){
            var middle_name = $('#middle_name').val();
            //alert(middle_name); //отладка
            function fill_middle_name()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "bold 20px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(middle_name, 100, 160);
            }
            fill_middle_name();
        });

        $('#post').blur(function(){
            var post = $('#post').val();
            //alert(post); //отладка
            function fill_post()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "bold 20px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(post, 40, 200);
            }
            fill_post();
        });

        $('#company').blur(function(){
            var company = $('#company').val();
            //alert(company); //отладка
            function fill_company()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "italic 40px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(company, 40, 80);
            }
            fill_company();
        });

        $('#address').blur(function(){
            var address = $('#address').val();
            //alert(address); //отладка
            function fill_address()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "bold 20px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(address, 40, 250);
            }
            fill_address();
        });

        $('#email').blur(function(){
            var email = $('#email').val();
            //alert(email); //отладка
            function fill_email()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "bold 20px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(email, 40, 380);
            }
            fill_email();
        });

        $('#phone').blur(function(){
            var phone = $('#phone').val();
            //alert(phone); //отладка
            function fill_phone()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "bold 20px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(phone, 40, 300);
            }
            fill_phone();
        });

        $('#mobile').blur(function(){
            var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
            //alert(mobile); //отладка
            function fill_mobile()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "bold 20px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(mobile, 40, 325);
            }
            fill_mobile();
        });

        $('#icq').blur(function(){
            var icq = $('#icq').val();
            //alert(icq); //отладка
            function fill_icq()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "bold 20px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(icq, 40, 400);
            }
            fill_icq();
        });

        $('#skype').blur(function(){
            var skype = $('#skype').val();
            //alert(skype); //отладка
            function fill_skype()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = elem.getContext('2d');

                context.font = "bold 20px "+ font;
                context.textBaseline = "bottom";
                context.fillText(skype, 40, 420);
            }
            fill_skype();
        });
        //Сохраняем то, что посетители вводят в значение полей в переменные -- КОНЕЦ
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <h1>Онлайн конструктор визиток</h1>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Поля для редактирования</legend>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="surname">Фамилия:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="surname">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_surname">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Имя:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_name">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="middle_name">Отчество:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="middle_name">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_middle_name">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="post">Должность:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="post">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_post">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="company">Название компании:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="company">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_company">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="address">Адрес:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="address">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_address">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_email">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="phone">Телефон:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_phone">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="mobile">Мобильный:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="mobile">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_mobile">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="icq">ICQ:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="icq">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_icq">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="skype">Skype:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="skype">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fill_skype">+</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" title="Добавить поле" class="btn btn-primary" id="add" onclick='reload();'>Добавить поле</a>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить визитку" class="btn btn-success">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="font">Шрифт:</label>
    <select id="font">
        <option>Arial</option>
        <option>Comic Sans MS</option>
        <option>Calibri</option>
        <option>Courier New</option>
        <option>Georgia</option>
        <option>Impact</option>
        <option>Tahoma</option>
        <option>Times New Roman</option>
        <option>Verdana</option>
    </select>
    <select id="font1">
        <option>bold</option>
        <option>italic</option>
        <option>underline</option>
    </select>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas><br>
    <a class="btn btn-warning">Очистить все</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне нужно вместо Arial поставить переменную font, которая берет свое значение из формы. Помогите составить правильную запись. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: @eprivalov1 Заголовок должен отражать суть вопроса.

Comment: Поправил заголовок!

Comment: [backbone.js delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)

    {
        'blur #surname'    : 'fill_surname',
        'blur #name'       : 'fill_name',
        'blur #middle_name': 'fill_middle_name',
        'blur #post'       : 'fill_post',
        ...
    }

не находите, что хорошо подходит для ваших целей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Смотрим пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/U4axT/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="font_field" value="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" />
<div id="context">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var font = document.getElementById('font_field').value;

var context = document.getElementById('context').style;
context.font = "italic 40px " + font;
```

Comment: Сейчас выложу свой код, у меня точно также, но не работает!

Comment: Обновил! У меня последняя версия Google Chrome

Comment: Не совсем "точно так же"... Сравните:

    // В моей вариации
    var context = document.getElementById('canvas').style;
    // в вашей
    var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

Comment: Так если я уберу .getContext('2d'), то я не смогу рисовать на холсте canvas. Мне нужно сделать вот так:
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d').style;
Правильно?

Comment: Я бы не особо мучался и просто создал бы объект для работы со стилями.

    var canvasStyle = document.getElementById('canvas').style;

Или же так:

    // оставляем как есть
    var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = elem.getContext('2d');

    // для стилей
    elem.style.font = "italic 40px " + font;

Comment: Спасибо, что пытаетесь мне помочь, я очень ценю любую помощь, но не работает не один пример. Видимо в Canvas 2d API все по-другому. Можете вставить мой код в JSFiddle и попробовать. Блин, я даже не знаю теперь, что мне делать.

Comment: В начале JS-скрипта объявите переменную     var font = 'Arial';Уберите **var** там, где задается новое значение для **font**    $('#font').blur(function(){        font = document.getElementById('font').value;    });И [все сразу заработает](http://jsfiddle.net/NEdXz/)

Answer (score 1):

Ну дык так же:

```
 var font = "Tahoma";
 context.style.fontFamily=font;
```

Comment: Я сделал точно так же, но так не хочет работать, к сожалению. Поэтому и задал тут вопрос.

Comment: Это вы просто неправильно стили меняли. Я поправил. Все работает.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, что именно я делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо почитать [HTML5 Canvas Steve Fulton & Jeff Fulton](http://www.google.co.uz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHgQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbook.tr200.net%2Fv.php%3Fid%3D1136162&ei=yN_6T8D7FbLc4QTIhfSVBw&usg=AFQjCNF_Jx_2qs2LJGbcVxLCk13Fk-pJEg), я пока не могу ответить на ваш вопрос (я сам только начал читать эту книгу) но уверен после прочтения этой книги все ваши вопросы по поводу `canvas` будут решены...